# Newsstand icon AND standalone icon?

Tags: objective-c, ios5, newsstand-kit

Having read Apple's numerous documentation on icon guidelines:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW2
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH6-SW1
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html

I was wondering if it was possible to have a newsstand icon and a standalone icon. I have my icons setup inside the info.plist (Primary Icon and Newsstand Icon for my iOS 5 only app), however, when I build my project, I'm only seeing my cover icon in the newsstand folder. I see the Guardian app has them both, so am I missing something else?

Edit: Added screenshot
[image]

Comment: Although the icon files are in the assets/icons group, they are physically in the root (same as main.m).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is working for my Newsstand application

[image: Plist file]

Make sure you have the same entries added in plist file.

Comment: I've edited my post to add a screenshot showing my files and plist. Can you see anything I'm doing wrong as I'm still not seeing a standalone icon.

Comment: "I'm only seeing my cover icon in the newsstand folder" what is is your cover icon ?

Comment: I'm seeing the correct ns_icon in the newsstand folder. I'm just not seeing any other icon outside the newsstand folder.

Comment: What do you mean by "not seeing any other icon outside the newsstand folder". NS application has ns_icon to show by default in newsstand folder. The newsstand application is ONLY available in Newsstand folder so there is nothing you see outside of that. The other icon in this case  may be iused for spotlight search or something else. Also note later when some issue is downloaded you should change newsstand icon with the cover of issue downloaded.

Comment: "The newsstand application is ONLY available in Newsstand folder so there is nothing you see outside of that." So that looks like the answer to my question "I was wondering if it was possible to have a newsstand icon and a standalone icon". Looks like it is not possible then. I saw that the Guardian app has a separate icon to the newsstand cover icon, so I presumed it was allowed. However, I'm thinking it's a different app now. Thanks for your response anyway.